# Using CassandraCSharpDriver 3.16.3, how to bind array parameters?

Tags: c#, cassandra, datastax, cql

I'm trying to bind an array of values to a IN clause in a PreparedStatement, but I'm not sure how.

This is a minimal example of what I'm trying to do:

```cs
private const string EXAMPLE_STATEMENT = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE owner = ? and bucket in (?)";

var _exampleStatement = new Lazy<Task<PreparedStatement>>(() => GetSession().PrepareAsync(EXAMPLE_STATEMENT));

var buckets = new List<double> { 4, 5, 6, 7 };
var result =  await GetSession().ExecuteAsync(
                (await _exampleStatement.Value).Bind(
                "foo",
                buckets
                ));
```

The equivalent in CQL would be:
`SELECT * FROM table WHERE owner = 'foo' and bucket in (4, 5, 6, 7);`

The binding of non-array parameters is working as intended.

I cannot use filtering (`bucket >= 4 and bucket <= 7`), as this field is part of the partition key.

Comment: What is the data type of the bucket column?

Comment: The type is double in the DB as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are likely 2 issues. First is that you don't need the parenthesis when preparing statement:

```
private const string EXAMPLE_STATEMENT = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE owner = ? and bucket in ?";
```

The second is that the CQL data type must match your C# data type when querying, i.e. `var buckets = new List<double> { 4, 5, 6, 7 };` means that the bucket column must be of double type. Refer to the docs [here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/csharp-driver/3.19/features/datatypes/) for the type mapping between CQL and C#.

Comment: Seems like the issue was indeed the parenthesis. Thank you!